# selecting all elements which are styled with a css gradient

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way, using only modern css, to select all elements which have a background-image which utilizes any sort of gradient and then overwrite that value with 'none'. Essentially, I need to wipe out all background gradients. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
*[background-image*="gradient"]{
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

I'm starting to think that attempting something like this is not sane, but I'd like to know for sure. Is this even possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[]` is for attributes so you would need to use `[style*=]` but this afaik would only work with inline styles (only fir gradients set with the `style` attr). Also assuming there is a way to query by currently applied css property your rule would not match anymore at the time you set `background` to `none`, so  the gradient would appear again, then the rule would match again, ... . So you would have either flickering or an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem using HTML and CSS.

You could use Javascript to check the `background-image` of every element in the DOM. With a huge DOM this can become slow, but seems like you have no other choice.

Comment: Why check *every* element? Surely you could check just the background-image value of elements that actually have a background-image attribute?

Comment: @adamwong246 But you cannot write a CSS selector for that. You have to look through all of them. All of them will have a `background-image` set - even though most of them will be at the default value, `none`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this method. you only have to add the class `gradient` for all those elements which are using gradient effect. I understand its a bit of work but it will solve your problem.

```
*[class*='gradient'] {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Answers are always directed @ the question. There is never a need to start an answer with the question asker's name.

Comment: Nope, I can't modify any html. (I'm writing a chrome extension which injects extra css into the user agent stylesheet.)